# XAMPP Apache site-root-relative links work locally, fail when accessing dev site via remote machine over LAN

Tags: apache, remote-access, lan

Am trying to set up multiple site development areas on a single server machine, then work on content from other computers over LAN. (Excuse the general wording of my questions, the site keeps preventing me from entering example URLs, etc.)

When I work directly on the server machine, entering

```
my-virtual-host-name:port#
```

as the URL everything works beautifully. It correctly resolves all links, image references, etc, as being relative to the site root.

When I connect from a different machine, over our Lan, entering

```
server-ip-address:port#
```

I get automatically redirected to a default XAMPP welcome page (So I am at least connecting to the server)

I figured how to setup an Alias statement, so that, for example something like

```
server-computer-ip-address:port#/alias-for-file-path
```

gets me to the home page for my site. But subsequently when I click on links, for example

```
/products-services
```

which I would want to go to

```
server-ip-address/alias-for-file-path/products-services
```

it instead resolves to

```
server-ip-address/products-services
```

### Relevant settings on the computer running the Apache server

IP Address: 192.168.22.12

In Windows Host file: 127.0.0.1 localhost mySiteName

In httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "D:\companysites\newproducts\mysite"
    ServerName mySiteName
  <Directory "D:\companysites\newproducts\mysite">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In httpd.conf (assigning alternate port to Apache, since 80 is otherwise used):

Listen 3399

Have tried a bunch of things not detailed here, trying to figure out how to correctly define some combination of server machine and remote machine virtual host definitions and url settings, as well as much web searching and zero luck so far!

Answer (score 0):

At present you've set it up so all Virtual Hosts are listening for the same connection. Same ip from all ports.  *

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, finally! Hopefully this will be useful and clear to someone else! (I am new to this, so may be obvious to others - there were some basic things I didn't understand and now do...)

In httpd-vhosts.conf file, you can:

1. Create any number of "Listen" statements, each with a unique port number. So, for example.

   Listen 8885

   Listen 8886

   Listen 8887
2. Then you can create any number of VirtualHost definition sections, associating one of the above ports with each, for example:

> ```
>     NameVirtualHost *
>  <VirtualHost 192.168.22.11:3399>
>    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
>    ServerName localhost
>  </VirtualHost>
>  <VirtualHost 192.168.22.11:3388>
>    DocumentRoot "file-system/path"
>    ServerName mySiteName
>  <Directory "file-system/path">
>    Order allow,deny
>    Allow from all
>  </Directory>
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

1. When connecting to the server from a remote computer, it is *not* possible to use any combination of alias server names and/or alias file path names (at least, didn't work for me - if there is a way, I'd be interested to know). Instead, always enter ip-address:port#, for example, enter, as the URL to one of the defined sub-domains on the server machine:

   192.168.22.11:3399